# Android white below activity on swipe to close by SwipeBackLayout library

Tags: android

i'm trying to use [SwipeBackLayout](https://github.com/liuguangqiang/SwipeBack) library to close and back to last activity, after install that and create simple activity like with the library, my below activity is white during swipe to close:

[image]

but i want to have that like with :

[image]

My sample activity:

```
public class DemoActivity extends SwipeBackActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
        setDragEdge(SwipeBackLayout.DragEdge.LEFT);
    }
}
```

sample activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/white"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i dont find other setting or other tips into library page and sample source

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="ThemeSwipeBack" parent="Theme.Swipe.Back" >
    // Your settings
</style>
```

Is important to set the parent to `Theme.Swipe.Back`

And then update your activity theme in `Manifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name=".BackActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeSwipeBack" />
```